# Need a TSQL query to select unique data in a table with 2 columns

Tags: sql, select

I have a table with 2 columns. I am trying to write a select statement that will select only the unique values. [screencap of data][1]
In my example you will see that there is repeating data in both columns, repeating data in one column is ok, but I need there to be only one occurrence of each row. I hope this makes sense.

```
+------------+--------------+
|  function  |  user        |
+------------+--------------+
|  add user  |  temp        |
|  add user  |  contractor  |
|  add user  |  full time   |
|  add user  |  temp        |
|  add user  |  contractor  |
|  add user  |  full time   |
|  del user  |  temp        |
|  del user  |  contractor  |
|  del user  |  full time   |
|  del user  |  temp        |
|  del user  |  contractor  |
|  del user  |  full time   |
+------------+--------------+
```

Comment: What brand of SQL are you using? What have you tried? http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM TABLE_NAME
```

[Distinct](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176104.aspx) filters out records with similar data based on the fields you specify, leaving you with only one row of that data. If you do not specify a column to filter by, then it will filter by all columns, ensuring that only one row of each duplicate will be shown.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DISTINCT`...

```
SELECT DISTINCT function, user 
FROM TableName
```

or use `Group By`

```
Select function, user 
FROM TableName
Group By function, user
```

This [`article`](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/12/20/sql-server-distinct-keyword-usage-and-common-discussion/) might be worth reading